# Generate Random ("Yes","No") by row in Excel and make 10% of random rows have value "Yes" and the rest as "No" value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

If I have 1200 rows, and I want 120 of my rows to say "Yes" and the rest to say "No", how should I apply this to an Excel file? I know to use:

```
=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,2),"Yes","No")
```

But I do  not know how to make it so that 10% of random rows will have "Yes" in their respective row. Is there a way to tweak this formula.

Comment: **Sidenote:** It would be great if you could revisit your previous 13 questions. Currently all your posts on SO are still open. Surely at least some of them have been answered. If so, see if you can accept some answers, even upvote those that have been helpfull.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally like this formula:

`If(rand()<0.1,"Yes","No")`

Of course, they are randomly distributed. So it won't be exactly 10%.

To make exactly 120 = "Yes" I would use a helper column with `=rand()`. Then next to it the formula `if(rank(b1,b:b)<121,"Yes","No")`

Answer (score 2):

With Microsoft365 you could try:

```
=IF(SORTBY(SEQUENCE(1200),RANDARRAY(1200))<121,"Yes","No")
```

Comment: When I try this, I get #NAME? on the rows, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You probably do not own the latest edition of Excel @IrwinMier.

Comment: Question, is that formula going to result in exactly 120 "yes" answers every time?

Comment: @Ilikeexcelverymuch. Indeed

Answer (score 1):

There is a general approach to this kind of question:

- I have a function, generating a random number between 0 and 1 (e.g. `rand()`).
- I want to have a certain value for 1/n cases.

Solution:

```
n * rand(), and check if the result is between 0 and 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting to have the distribution be exactly 10% - 90% or is this just a target.
You could use `=IF(RANDBETWEEN(1,10) = 1,"YES", "NO")`